# In an AFS filesystem, why am I unable to access some directories where I have r-x permissions, and able to access some where I have no permissions?

Tags: linux, file-permissions, afs

I've encountered some unexpected behavior when trying to access directories in an AFS mount using Linux (specifically, in bash 4.3.11(1)-release on Ubuntu 14.04.1). In some cases, I'm unable to access directories that I should be able to access, and in others I *am* able to access some directories where I have no permissions at all. For example:

```
$ ls -l
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 9   70296     root     6144  Jan 12 14:44 look_inside
drwx------ 278 someadmin operator 10240 Jan 17 17:54 private
<output truncated>
$ cd look_inside
-bash: cd: look_inside: Permission denied
$ ls look_inside
ls: cannot open directory look_inside: Permission denied
```

I am not the owner and I'm not in group `root`, so the everyone permissions should apply to look_inside. Everyone has `r-x` permissions for `look_inside` and all its parent directories, and yet I'm unable to use `cd look_inside` or `ls look_inside`. On the other hand, I *can* access `private`, even though I have no permissions:

```
$ getfacl private
# file: private
# owner: cbl
# group: operator
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
$ ls -l private
total 560
<output truncated>
```

I'm not the owner of `private`, either. I am in group `operator`, but that shouldn't matter since the group doesn't have any permissions for `private`. And yet, I'm able to access private. That said, I can't access any of the directories inside it, whether or not I have `r-x` permissions (see below). That makes sense, of course, because I don't have x permission on their parent. There are no regular files in `private` (or at least, I'm only shown directories when I run `ls`), so I don't know how regular files are affected.

```
$ cd private
$ ls -l
total 560
drwx------ 3 someadmin  operator 2048 Jan 16 14:11 someuser
drwxr-xr-x 3 otheradmin operator 2048 Jan 16 14:11 otheruser
<output truncated>
$ ls -l someuser
ls: cannot open directory someuser: Permission denied
$ ls -l otheruser
ls: cannot open directory otheruser: Permission denied
```

What could be causing this behavior? Is there any way for me to access `look_inside`? Should I (or the system's admin) be concerned that I'm able to access `private`?

Comment: what does `df -T .` say?

Comment: `df -T .` shows that the type is afs and that all blocks available (0% use). I didn't realize that it was relevant that this was AFS, but I'm guessing from your comment that it's important.

Comment: OK, so it appears that the usual linux permissions don't apply in AFS, even though `ls -l` will happily display them. AFS has its own permissions system that only works at a directory scope. Information about a directory's permissions can be obtained with `fs la directory_name`. Once I knew that this had to do with AFS, I was able to find [this helpful link](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3907002).

Comment: @greggo, would you like to submit an answer to this question?

Comment: @rhymes-with-dorange I don't have an answer; I just thought that knowing the filesystem would be important - since I've not seen this behaviour with the FS's I've had experience with. Thanks for editing the question to specify it's AFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFS does not use traditional Unix permissions (though it does remember them), nor POSIX ACLs (what you see with `getfacl`). There are some exceptions with Unix permissions (if you remove *all* access to read or write with `chmod`, I believe that does remove the relevant access for everyone), but generally speaking AFS uses its own ACL system.

Assuming you are using OpenAFS, to see the permissions on a file or directory, run `fs listacl <path>`. To set the permissions, if you have access, run `fs setacl <path> <user> <perms>`. The permissions granted by AFS ACLs are different from both Unix `chmod`-style permissions, POSIX ACLs, and, well, any other access system I'm aware of. They are explained in detail [here](http://docs.openafs.org/UserGuide/HDRWQ46.html), but briefly: you have 7 permissions, usually represented by a single letter. They are: 'r'ead, 'l'ist, 'w'rite, 'i'nsert, 'd'elete, loc'k', and 'a'dmin.

So for example, a directory you can look at and read files in would look like this:

```
$ fs listacl somedir
Access list for somedir is
Normal rights:
   system:anyuser rl
   system:administrators rlidwka
```

Which means that 'system:anyuser' (anybody in the world) can only 'l' the directory contents, and 'r'ead the contents of files in that dir. On the other hand, 'system:administrators' (a group used for admin users) can do anything.

A directory that you cannot access might look like this:

```
$ fs listacl privdir
Access list for privdir is
Normal rights:
   system:administrators rlidwka
   foouser rlidwka
```

Which means that only administators and 'foouser' can do anything to that directory. However, if you can't access a directory at all, I think you also won't be able to `fs listacl` it, so that will show an error message instead.

If you're not using OpenAFS, but are instead using the AFS implementation in the upstream Linux source tree ("kAFS"), then you won't have the `fs` command. I don't believe it's possible to view AFS ACLs with that implementation, but I could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

Access Control Lists can do that. Did you check your username and groups in the bash session? `whoami` and `groups`

Comment: Yes, I checked the username and groups and they were what I expected. The output in `getfacl private` shows that there aren't any ACLs here, right?